# validation error message not showing laravel 5.4

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, validation

messages.blade.php

```
@if(count($errors) > 0)
@foreach($errors->all() as $error)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {{$error}}
    </div>
@endforeach
@endif
```

main.blade.php

```
<body class="nav-md">
<div class="container body">
    @include('messages')
  <div class="main_container">
```

AddInfocontroller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $this->validate($request,[
    'fileno' => 'required|unique:AddInfoModel|max:255',
  ]);
```

input name = fileno 
I tried to leave as empty fileno field 
after click submit not error showing

In case post the date through ajax function, maybe that why error doesn't showing or any other mistake .If that the case ,how to sort out form it well ?

Comment: your form and error message page different wright?

Comment: ya , i include that @whoami

Comment: dont seperate form and error, both are depend on each other

Comment: You partially included the messages.blade.php in your main.blade.php. So you have to pass $errors to messages view also. @include('messages',$errors)

Answer (score 0):

In controller make validation and return error message to view

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
             'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
             'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
             'email' => 'required|email|max:255'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return back()->withErrors($validator->errors())
                         ->withInput($request->all());
        }
```

Comment: Do not forget to use "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;" in controller

Answer (score -2):

//CONTROLLER CODES

```
$validator = $this->validate($request->all(), [
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return back()->withErrors($validator->errors())
        ->withInput($request->all());
}
```

//VIEW CODES

```
@if($errors->has())
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <div>{{ $error }}</div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```